# Efficient algorithm fir finding the smallest and largest elements of an array

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to achieve time complexity O (n log n) for my algorithm that I have been using. What it does is looks at a list of numbers and first the highest number, lowest number, and the profit obtained from the two. How do I modified my code to get the time complexity I am looking for?

Code:

```
while (i < a.length)
      {
         for (int j = i; j < a.length; j++)
         {
            if(a[j] - a[i] > profit)
            {
               lowestIndex = i;
               highestIndex = j;
               profit = a[j] - a[i];
            }
         }  
         i++;
      }
```

Comment: This is n-squared. Any algorithm with two outer loops incremented by one like this will be (at least) n-squared. To get n-log-n from a sorting algorithm you need a smarter inner loop doing something like heap insertion, quicksort partitioning, or the like.

Comment: There's no need to sort an array in order to find the highest value and the lowest value. Why do you think you need nested loops?

Comment: See the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem, which has a linear time algorithm.

Comment: So how exactly would I change my program to manipulate that?

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.sort()` is a sorting function that supposedly runs at O(n log n).

You can check the Arrays API for more info. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])

For code, I'd implement it this way. I don't know if it's the most efficient implementation out there.

```
Arrays.sort(a); // sort in ascending order
profit = a[a.length-1] - a[0];
```